# Best way to replace nth character of a string but ignores white space?

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to figure out the best way to replace the nth character of a string but ignore the space when looping. For example, if I was to change every 5th character of the String `mary had a little lamb` to `z`, it should return `mary zad azlittze lazb`

One way I thought would be to remove all space (`maryhadalittlelamb`), then change all the 5th character to `z` (`maryzadazlittzelazb`) and then reference the original string, find the index of `" "` and insert it into `maryzadazlittzelazb`

But this doesn't seem very elegant and I'm sure theres a better way to do this, could someone please advise?

Thanks!

Comment: loop in the string and for every nth character replace it with replacement character only if it is string

Comment: I get "mary zad a lzttle zamb". How do you get `azlittze` from `a little`?

Comment: Sorry I might have just confused myself but does this help|? 
mary zad a lzttle zamb => 1234 512 3 451234 5123

Comment: I would use a regular expression replace all: a regular expression like `((\S\s*){4})\S` will match (and remember) 4 characters with spaces interleaved that are followed by one character, which you could then replace with `\1z` - that will put the 4 characters and interleaved spaces it remembered followed by a z...

Comment: Is Nawnit's method not good enough?  it seems like looping through the string and counting the chars is the simplest and pretty efficient only making 1 loop though the string.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [`String.toCharArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--), then iterate with a regular `for` loop and test if each character is not whitespace with [`Character.isWhitespace(char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace-char-). If it's not, increment the second counter (here named `p`) and check if that value is divisible by five. If so, set it to `z`. Finally, create a new `String` based on the edited `char[]`. Like,

```
String str = "mary had a little lamb";
char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0, p = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (!Character.isWhitespace(arr[i]) && ++p % 5 == 0) {
        arr[i] = 'z';
    }
}
System.out.println(new String(arr));
```

I get (as I mentioned in the comments)

```
mary zad a lzttle zamb
```

Also, because it might not be very clear, the complex `if` above is equivalent to

```
if (!Character.isWhitespace(arr[i])) {
    p++;
    if (p % 5 == 0) {
        arr[i] = 'z';
    }
}
```

Comment: if we have to be maximalists - you can exit a bit earlier from the loop (if the leftover is less than 5) ;)

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, my suggestion would have looked like this:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("((\\S\\s*){4})\\S");
  Matcher m = p.matcher("mary had a little lamb");
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
  while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, "$1z");
  }
  m.appendTail(sb);
  System.out.println(sb.toString()); 
}
```

Comment: Your solution return "mary zad a lzttle zamb", but should "mary zad azlittze lazb" (as at question). Test also "m a r y had a liitle lamb".

Comment: @MikhailIonkin if I am replacing every 5th char, ignoring whitespace, I don't see how i am expected to replace the space between "a" and "little" with a z ...

Comment: ok, i see comments for question. Your solution passed my tests